# Wordpress Master Slider Responsive Issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, slider, responsive

I'm using the master slider plugin for my wordpress site and have an issue with the slider not being responsive.

For example if you load the browser at max-width:500px and stretch the browser 500px+ the slider dose not respond and basically stays stuck at the width it loaded in.

Any ideas will kindly be appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: Is this the plugin you're using? https://wordpress.org/plugins/master-slider/ also what's the URL of your site?

Comment: @bezierer Yes thats the one... Any thoughts? Here is the site URL: http://www.greatbocasmiles.com/

Comment: So it looks like the slider is setting the width as an inline style via JS which isn't getting updated as you stretch the browser width. You may want to reach out to them on their support forum on wordpress.org to see if the devs have a fix or other solution.